# How to use hide iframe based on condition in angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to hide my `<iframe></iframe>` if(id != 1).I am getting id from `{{test.id}}` which I am getting from a query

I am new in angular, I am from C# background but currently working in angular 6 .How can i resolve this issue.

Comment: I want to hide my <iframe></iframe> on if condition.

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<iframe *ngIf="test.id !=1"><iframe>
```

or

```
<ng-container *ngIf="test.id !=1">
    <iframe></iframe>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thank you Omair Nabiel and Adrita sharma .

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe *ngIf="test.id !== 1">    
</iframe>
```

for if else

```
<iframe *ngIf="test.id !== 1; else otherContent">    

</iframe>

<ng-template #otherContent>

</ng-template>
```

Comment: ngif is only working for number ? if i  want to use string just like "<div *ngIf="prod.productName =='FLIP BOOK'; then ifcondition else elsecondition"></div>" if is valid or not.

Comment: <div *ngIf="prod.klasActPreviewimages && prod.productName == 'FLIP BOOK'; then ifcondition else elsecondition"></div>
<div class="flipbook-img" #ifcondition> <img  /></div>
<div class="cameracover" #elsecondition>
<div class="cameraicon"> <img /> <p>Choose Photo</p> </div></div> my this code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div *ngIf="selectedStudent.schoolId == 29; then ifcondition else elsecondition"></div>
<template #ifcondition>
    <iframe id="myIframe" onload="delayedLoad()"></iframe>
</template>
<template #elsecondition>
  <span> Else Condition Works!</span>
</template>
```

this is my answer and working in my condition.